# Kubernetes yaml file not working as a helm template

Tags: kubernetes, cron, gitlab, kubernetes-helm

I know this is a repeated question however, I didn't get an answer that satisfies my query. I am trying to create a helm chart for cronjob deployment. I keep the helm chart name as cronjob-example.

Now when I run the command `helm install` or `helm upgrade` manually I can install or update the cronjob however when I try to do the same from CICD pipeline it fails with error converting file YAML to JSON on line 19 of `templates/cronjob.yaml` file.

cronjob.yaml file.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  namespace: {{ .Values.metadata.namespace }}
  creationTimestamp: {{ .Values.metadata.creationTimestamp }}
  name: {{ .Values.name }}
spec:
  jobTemplate:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: {{ .Values.metadata.creationTimestamp }}
      name: {{ .Values.name }}
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
          creationTimestamp: {{ .Values.metadata.creationTimestamp }}
        spec:
          imagePullSecrets:
            - name: {{ .Values.image.imagePullSecrets }}
          containers:
          - image: {{ .Values.image.repository }}
            name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
            resources: {}
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
  schedule: '*/1 * * * *'
status: {}
```

values.yaml file

```
---
metadata:
  namespace: "{{K8S_NS}}"

name: "{{HELM_APP_NAME}}"
#name: "cronjob-example"

nodeLabel: agent

image:
  repository: "{{CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}}/{{CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}}:{{CI_COMMIT_SHA}}.{{CI_PIPELINE_IID}}"
  pullPolicy: "Always"
  imagePullSecrets: git-image-pull-secret-cron
  creationTimestamp: null

variables:
- name: "TLS_ENV"
  value: "tst"
```

I am wondering why it is successful when I run it manually and why it fails through CICD pipeline.  Everything works in CICD pipeline as is except the deployment stage. There it fails. All I am doing is hard coding the values I get from previous stages in cicd when I am installing/upgrading manually.

Comment: How are you filling in the placeholders in your values.yml? Can you post an example how the values.yml looks that is generated your CI job?

Comment: I have gitlab CICD variables set for `K8S_NS` like variables and `CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE` like variables are standard variables provided by gitlab. I already have this kind of implementation working for deployments now I want to implement it cronjob.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is this location in your template.

```
- image: {{ .Values.image.repository }}
```

The substituted value for   `repository: "{{CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}} /{{CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}}:{{CI_COMMIT_SHA}}.{{CI_PIPELINE_IID}}"` results in an invalid value.

Comment: These are standard variables provided by gitlab. Please have a look at this --> https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html

Comment: @ShaileshSutar I understand that. But without some kind of logic these won't magically be filled in your values.yml. So did you setup a mechanism to put these into you values.yaml?

Comment: Thank you Lukas and Harsh. I figured out what my issue was. We are using j2 templates in the deployment. And values.yaml is actually a j2 template like values.yaml.j2 which does all the placeholder replacements. The file was just named as values.yaml. I needed that file to be values.yaml.j2

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned there is issue at line number 19 which is

```
- image: {{ .Values.image.repository }}
```

you might be giving proper value when trying locally and check what values are getting passed during the CI for

```
repository: "{{CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}} /{{CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG}}:{{CI_COMMIT_SHA}}.{{CI_PIPELINE_IID}}"
```

if you want to debug more you can also try

`helm install --dry-run --debug` or `helm template --debug`

It's a great way to have the server render your templates, then return the resulting manifest file.